# Using Two URLs on a Website using PHP/MYSQL

Tags: php, url

This applies to such things CMS or Message Board Systems or the Like. Most of these have a config.php file where the domain name for the site will be found/located at.

My question is, is it possible to use more than one domain name (not redirecting or pointing), but if they go to www.mybrand.com all links will proceed with mybrand.com because of the config.php file listing it as the uRL. I'm looking for one (PHP code) that if they go to mybrand.net or .com it will check what URL is being used and if mybrand.com is used all links on the site will be .com (vise-versa for .net).

Is this possible?

Comment: Just use relative or absolute path URLs, ie `<a href="/foo">` instead of `<a href="http://mybrand.com/foo">`

Comment: But, config.php is URL specific and such things (Wordpress or Invision Power Board). Unless that doesn't matter.

Comment: I literally have no idea what you're asking

Comment: I have no idea either - surely if they click on a link to mybrand.com all links on that site will be .com and if they click on mybrand.net all links on that site will be .net ?